# Using SVG file in HTML5 and change color

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use a svg file as image in my website. I am using this:

```
<object id="mysvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="logo.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

It shows the image in page. But now I want to modify the image. This is a one color(black) image. and I want to make it white. Like fill with white. What is the best way to do that? Can I also achieve the same result on hover of the image?
Thanks

Comment: Can you check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619600/consistently-change-background-colour-upon-hovering-over-an-svg-link.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the image from the html container using something like this:

```
var svgdoc = document.getElementById("mysvg").contentDocument;
var svgElement = svgdoc.getElementById("whatever the Id is of the black image");
svgElement.setAttribute("fill", "white");
```

For hover you'll need to put the logic in the logo.svg file itself i.e. create a `<style>` element and make a hover pseudo class rule to change the colour on hover.